# Is it possible to clone `skip_while`?

Tags: rust

`std::iter::SkipWhile` has a `Clone` implementation, but when I try to call `clone()` on it, I get:

```
let a = [-1i32, 0, 1];
let mut iter = a.into_iter().skip_while(|x| x.is_negative()).clone();
```

> the method `clone` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `[closure@<anon>:3:45: 3:64] : core::clone::Clone`

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20a%20%3D%20[-1i32%2C%200%2C%201]%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20iter%20%3D%20a.into_iter%28%29.skip_while%28|x|%20x.is_negative%28%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20assert_eq!%28iter.next%28%29%2C%20Some%28%260%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_eq!%28iter.next%28%29%2C%20Some%28%261%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_eq!%28iter.next%28%29%2C%20None%29%3B%0A%7D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the closure doesn't implement `Clone`. This is a known issue in Rust: [#23501](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23501).

What if we use a normal function instead of a closure? Your closure doesn't capture anything, after all.

```
fn main() {
    fn is_negative(x: &&i32) -> bool {
        x.is_negative()
    }

    let a = [-1i32, 0, 1];

    let mut iter = a.into_iter().skip_while(is_negative).clone();

    assert_eq!(iter.next(), Some(&0));
    assert_eq!(iter.next(), Some(&1));
    assert_eq!(iter.next(), None);
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, since functions don't implement `Clone` either (although they implement `Copy`!). This is also a known issue: [#24000](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24000), [#28229](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28229).

Comment: Actually, they're different problems.  A `fn` pointer can be pretty trivially cloned, it just doesn't have the implementation.  A closure is harder, because whether or not it can be cloned depends on whether the values it captures can be cloned, and *how* they're captured can affect that.  Plus, that starts to get into "how do you specify which traits a closure should impl" and it all gets messy very fast.

Comment: Right. I just searched for and found a separate issue for closures, so I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!